# Compute 2D Character Route

Tags: android, libgdx, game-physics

at the moment I create an Java 2D Game which include a Character that moves on rectangle platforms in x/y direction. The problem is the route which the Character is allowed to move. So, the Character may move on the platforms but not outside of this. At the moment I write for each level with different ways which the character is allowed to move a lot of Code with terms for the x/y position of the Character. 
My question is: Is there a simple way for compution the route of the specific levels?

Sorry for my bad english :(

greetings Fabian!

Comment: You could use some sort of `PathFinding`, for example A* (A-Star). All you need to know is the start point, end point and if a position is "blocked" or not.

Comment: Springrbua@ Thanks for your answer. But the problem is that the character is allowed in every direction with a joystick. So the Character is allowed to move on a rectangle-platform to every border. So at the moment I check every position with a "if" statement, if he may to stay at their position. Do you need an example of picture for that? My english is very bad :D

Comment: So you are looking for some kind of `Collision Detection`? A picture would be nice, it would make it easier to understand your question. (P.S.: I guess you speek german like me right?)